# Regular expression capturing utf-8 line separators

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

It seems Javascript's native regular expressions fail to capture strings with interpolated line separator characters U+2028. For example when I try:

```
"a\u2028b".match(/(.*)/)
```

I can capture only "a" and not the full string.

Is there a reason for this behavior or it's just Javascript failing to manage some utf-8 characters? Is there a way to work around this problem using Javascript's native regular expressions?

Comment: `\u2028` seems to be handled the same way as `\n`, thus is not matched by `.`. Do you want it to behave as a regular char rather than a line separator?

Comment: After seeing the accepted answer, I have to say that the question was totally misleading. It has nothing to do with UTF-8 or exotic Unicode code-points: it's a mere misunderstanding of what `.` stands for in regular expressions. You'd have the very same problem with good old `\n` character.

Comment: I failed to understand that Javascript manages utf-8 better than other non utf-8 aware programming languages managing utf-8 line separators as expected. That's why the question could have been misleading, and that's why I asked and gave a practical example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
"a\u2028b".match(/^[\s\S]*$/);
// matches ab
```

In javascript `.` doesn't match newlines therefore `[\s\S]` is used to match newlines as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's how it's supposed to work. For purposes of matching the `.`, `^` and `$` metacharacters, `U+2028` and `U+2029` are classified as line separators along with `\r` carriage return) and `\n` (linefeed).

...in JavaScript, that is.  Every regex flavor has its own idea of which characters are line separators.  For example, Java recognizes all of those plus `U+0085` (next-line or NEL) character, while .NET only recognizes `\n`.

Comment: Last but not least, `U+2028` is a **Unicode** code-point and you can use the `\u2028` syntax to represent it in a JavaScript string. None of those are related to UTF-8, where that same char is represented as `e280a8`.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely why I've used \u2028, to represent that character for the example.